# Laravel not loading public/resource files

Tags: php, laravel, server

I am using the php server file for local development temporarly. I use localhost:8888 for my laravel application as this:

```
php -S localhost:8888 server.php
```

Laravel loads, I can create new Routes etc.. But unfortunatly I seem to be unable to load any CSS files from the public folder.

Since the other similar questions on stackoverflow seem to include .htaccess file, here is mine from the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my Route:

```
Route::get('/about', array('as'=>'about',function()
{
    return View::make('bootstraped');
}));
```

This is my 'blade' attempt to load the file:

```
{{HTML::style('css/main.css');}}
```

Which is printed as a proper link..

This is my php template attempt (I have also tried putting public before css (no luck)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/bootstrap-theme.css');?>" type="text/css">
```

And this is the console output in chrome:

```
 GET http://localhost:8888/css/bootstrap.min.css 
about:23 GET http://localhost:8888/css/main.css 
about:25 GET http://localhost:8888/css/bootstrap-theme.css 
about:27 GET http://localhost:8888/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js 
about:95 GET http://localhost:8888/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js 
about:97 GET http://localhost:8888/js/main.js
```

I have sett correct rights for storage folder and tried 777 on public folder..

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of things here. [Read this link](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-5-4-built-in-webserver)!

PHP's built in server doesn't use htaccess to my knowledge. Also you are executing server.php from outside your actual webroot. So you will need to need to specify the proper webroot.